# "[Required]" Data Annotation Not Enforced on POST Methods

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, model-validation, asp.net-web-api2

I had the idea to use Data Annotations in order to validate ModelState. This works wonderfully. The problem I am having is that the [Required] Data Annotation is being enforced on [Key] fields on post. Our data layer takes care of setting Id's and we don't want anyone consuming the service to have to worry about Id's. Is there a way around this in WebApi2?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375199/webapi-post-not-to-include-id-field) question, and removing the Id field from ModelState in the POST method before checking for valid ModelState would work. The issue with that is that we use a filter for ModelState.

**EDIT:**

After doing some more research, what I am essentially wanting to do is what the [Bind] attribute does in MVC. After some research, it does not look like this is a feature that has yet been implemented in WebApi. If anyone has any ideas, feel free to post them.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to replace your entity with a data transfer object, which is identical to your original entity without the ID field. For example,

The original entity may look like this

```
public class User 
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

and the DTO may look like this

```
public class UserDto 
    {

        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

Hope this helps.